# How to create Curve between two points using **Vector3.MoveTowards**?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform

i'm working on a game something like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitmango.rolltheballunrollme).I have set up waypoints to let player go ahead. I am stuck at how to add curvy movements on turn ? As you can see in ref I have to add lot of waypoints continuously side by side to give a curve movement to it but it is not working properly as player do not move in curve instead it moves robotically.

Comment: There are Bezier Curve tutorial all over the internet and unitypackage in asset store, by searching you can find it.

http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/

Also iTween support these kind of paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use approximation or Bezier curve instead interpolation.